# Limiting Http Requests in Yii Controller

Tags: php, yii

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'allow',
            'actions' => array('create', 'update'),
            'users' => array('@'),
            'verbs' => array('POST')
        ),
        array(
            'allow',
            'actions' => array('view'),
            'users' => array('@'),
            'verbs' => array('GET')
        ),
        array(
            'deny',
            'users' => array('*'),
            // 'verbs' => array('GET')
        ),
    );
}
```

I currently have that code above in my controller. I want to limit access to the update and create methods. They need only be accessed via POST requests.

The above currently doesn't work. Can anyone shed some light?

Note: My reference from the Larry Ullman's Yii Book.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I got the answer.

```
public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }
```

The filter method should be available for the accessControl to be fully functional.